# What does 'string-like' and 'byte-like' mean?

Tags: python, string

Reading about Python types the description `string-like` or `byte-like` captured my attention. I couldn't find a proper definition what those exactly mean andhow to use those terms properly. I read for example in `Python Cookbook` the following section:

> `basestring` is a common base class for the `str` and `unicode` types, and any **string-like** type that user code might define should also subclass `basestring`, just to make sure that such `isinstance` testing works as intended.

So is it now correct to say that anything deriving from `basestring` can be considered **string-like**? Even than what makes it `string-like`, it's return type?

Answer (score 4):

`<type>-like` is any object that *acts just like that type*. Python widely relies on *duck typing*; if it walks and quacks like a duck, it *is* a duck. If it behaves like a string, it probably is one.

So the documentation is telling you that if you are going to create a custom type that wants to be treated like a string everywhere, it may be an idea to subclass `basestring`.  That way any code that explicitly wants to test for string types (bytes or unicode text) by using `isinstance(obj, basestring)` will accept your custom type too.

You still have to implement the minimum set of expected methods; inheriting from `basestring` won't magically make your type *work*. That *minimum set* depends on how the code you are trying to dupe is manipulating the strings. Your type has to be string-like *enough* to dupe whatever you are using your type for.

Yes, that's deliberately vague, and not all code can be duped (some built-in functions and types expect to be able to use the C API on string objects, or even reach into the `str` internals). Often it is easier to just subclass `str` or `unicode` to ensure nothing is missed.

The language has since stepped away from such base classes, and has defined [*abstract base classes*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class) instead, which, together with [hooks for customising subclass and instance checks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks) now are the recommended way to do duck typing in one check.